# primefaces commandButton not set input field value in ui:repeat

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have list in view scoped bean. The #{repeatController.add} a new object to the list. It call the h:commandButton and the p:commandButton also.

My problem is, when I have a new line, typing into the "repeatName" field something, after press h:commandButton or p:commandButton, they have different working.

The h:commandButton push the new field value to the bean and it appeared after refresh the form and the new line also.

The p:commandButton not push the new field value to the bean. After refresh the form the new line appeared, but the previously typed content of the "repeatName" field is empty.

I think the h:commandButton working fine, the p:commandButton is not working fine.

The "noRepeatName" field value always set with h:commandButton and p:commandButton.

Steps and result with h:commandButton:

1. push the button (create new line) more times.
2. type to the "noRepeatName" field
3. type to the the first "repeatName" field
4. push the button

Result: after refresh, previously typed content of the field appeared.

Steps and result with p:commandButton:

1. push the button (create new line) more times.
2. type to the "noRepeatName" field
3. type to the the first "repeatName" field
4. push the button

Result: after refresh, previously typed content of the "noRepeatName" field appeared, but the first "repeatName" is empty.

Do I miss something?
Why doesn't set the value of the first "repeatName" filed to the bean like with h:commandButton?

I use primefaces 6.2.10, jsf 2.2.18 (oracle) and spring boot 2.0.6.

JSF code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head/>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="repeatForm">
        <h:commandButton value="plus" id="addJsf">
            <f:ajax event="click" immediate="true" render="repeatForm" execute="repeatForm"
                    listener="#{repeatController.add}"/>
        </h:commandButton>
        <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-plus" actionListener="#{repeatController.add}" immediate="true" id="add"
                         process="repeatForm" update="repeatForm"/><br/>
        <p:inputText value="#{repeatData.name}" id="noRepeatName">
            <f:validateLength minimum="30"/>
        </p:inputText><br/>
        <ui:repeat value="#{repeatData.products}" var="product" varStatus="productStatus">
            First: #{productStatus.first}"; Last: #{productStatus.last}; Index: #{productStatus.index}<br/>
            <p:inputText value="#{product.name}" id="repeatName">
               <f:validateLength minimum="20"/>
            </p:inputText><br/>
        </ui:repeat>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Java bean

```
@Named
@Scope("view)
public class RepeatData {
    private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();

    private String name;

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Product

```
public class Product {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Controller

```
@Named
@Scope("request")
public class RepeatController {
    @Autowired
    private RepeatData repeatData;

    public void add() {
        repeatData.getProducts().add(new Product());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why exactly are you using `immediate="true"`? It's a poor practice in JSF 2.x and most likely the cause of your observable problem.

Comment: @BalusC Because of validators. I was forget to mention it. (I was edited the the xhtml)